# setImmediate vs setTimeout vs nextTick

Tags: node.js

Since event loop runs in phases and it enters the timer phase first. Why doesnt `setTimeout` get executed first since `setTimeout` has `0` value and the timer should be expired the first time event loop enters timers phase.

1st:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout');
  }, 0);
  
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('immediate');
  });
```

Output from running:

```
timeout
immediate
```

Output from running again:

```
immediate
timeout
```

2nd. This behavior is different than what I see in the following function:

```
setImmediate(() => {
  console.log("Immediate");
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Timeout");
}, 0);

process.nextTick(() => {
  console.log("Nexttick");
});

console.log("Hello");
```

----------It always outputs `setTimeout` with 0 value before `setImmediate` which is what I expect before setTimeout with 0 value is an expired timer right from the start.

```
node AuthenticationController.js
Hello
Nexttick
Timeout
Immediate

node AuthenticationController.js
Hello
Nexttick
Timeout
Immediate
PS C:\Users\vskk0\OneDrive\Documents\nprs-backend\AuthenticationComponent>
```

Why does the 2nd function always prints timeout before immediate  but not the 1st one?

Answer (score 0):

In the first function the reason sometimes the setTimeout is executed after the setImmediate is because it will check the timer at least once before executing. But you must take into consideration that setTimeout() callback with a 0ms delay is very similar to setImmediate(). The execution order will depend on various factors, but they will be both run in the next iteration of the event loop. I gathered some info that might help you from old questions:

[NodeJS - setTimeout(fn,0) vs setImmediate(fn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117267/nodejs-settimeoutfn-0-vs-setimmediatefn)

[the difference between `setTimeout` and `setImmediate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985065/the-difference-between-settimeout-and-setimmediate)

[How is timing of `setImmediate()` and `setTimeout()` bound by the performance of the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834122/how-is-timing-of-setimmediate-and-settimeout-bound-by-the-performance-of)

**You might also want to check this from the node.js docs:**

https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/understanding-setimmediate/

Comment: why doesnt it happen in the second one?

Comment: In the second one the setTimout managed to check its timer while the console.log and the nextTick was executing so now it was ready to execute before setImmediate.

Comment: Why wasnt it able to do it in the first one? Time issue?